# audio html5 with jquery to play next track

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have html5 like this

```
<audio controls class="audioPlayer" >
     <source class="iSong" src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
     <source class="iSong" src="2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
     <source class="iSong" src="3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
     Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I want add jquery for button nextSong because my song always play only last one.

Comment: Can you share code, that you tried ? This page is not about coding for you for free. Try it yourself :)

Comment: If you want to add button, then what you waiting for? Just add it :P

Answer (score 0):

Adding multiple sources to an audio element does not create a playlist, it is to support different audio formats and your browser will simply play the first one it can, which is why you say only the last one is playing.

To have multiple songs you choose between you will have to write some javascript. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) is some information on audio in javascript.

It sounds like you will have to create a separate button for playing the next song, add a click event that changes the source of the audio element and plays it.